# how to disable/enable WIFI radio in Windows-CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How to disable/enable WIFI radio in Windows-CE?

(not in Windows-Mobile)

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to power the radio off.  You'll need to check with the hardware vendor (possibly the WiFi card, possibly the board/device depending on how the radio is attached) to see if they provide an API for it.